# extract url from string with Javascript

Tags: javascript

this sounds like something you could just google, but been looking for hours.

basically have this string i am ajaxing from another site

```
'function onclick(event) { toFacebook("http://www.domain.com.au/deal/url-test?2049361208?226781981"); }'
```

it comes out like that because im extracting the onclick.

i just want to extract the url from the string.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

---- edit ----

OK IF I GO HERE..http://regexlib.com/RESilverlight.aspx regext online tester

and run this regex.

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

on my string, it highlights the url perfectly.. i just can get it to run with JS?

Comment: It looks to me like the string *is* the URL...

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url?

Answer (score 3):

if it is always with the dash (i'm assuming you want everything before the dash), you can use the split method:

```
var arr = split(val);
```

your data will be in arr[0]

Answer (score 0):

you can use these functions in javascript:

```
function parseUrl1(data) {
var e=/^((http|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+\.[^#?\s]+)(#[\w\-]+)?$/;

if (data.match(e)) {
    return  {url: RegExp['$&'],
            protocol: RegExp.$2,
            host:RegExp.$3,
            path:RegExp.$4,
            file:RegExp.$6,
            hash:RegExp.$7};
}
else {
    return  {url:"", protocol:"",host:"",path:"",file:"",hash:""};
}
}

function parseUrl2(data) {
var e=/((http|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+\.[^#?\s]+)(#[\w\-]+)?/;

if (data.match(e)) {
    return  {url: RegExp['$&'],
            protocol: RegExp.$2,
            host:RegExp.$3,
            path:RegExp.$4,
            file:RegExp.$6,
            hash:RegExp.$7};
}
else {
    return  {url:"", protocol:"",host:"",path:"",file:"",hash:""};
}
}
```

References :http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-parse.php

Comment: same, somethings broken blank object

Answer (score 0):

just ended up doing this

```
$a.substring($a.indexOf("http:"), $a.indexOf("?"))
```

regular expressions are beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

`yourFunction.toString().split("'")[1]` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var urlRegex = /(http?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;

    var testUrl = text.match(urlRegex);

    if (testUrl === null) {

    return "";

      }else {

    var urlImg = testUrl[0];

    return urlImg;

     }
```

Answer (score -3):

**Edit:**
Here is another solution that will extract the url:

```
var function = 'function onclick(event) { toFacebook("http://www.domain.com.au/deal/url-test?2049361208?226781981"); }'
function.match(/(http:[^"]+)/)[0]
```

**Old answer:**
Use Regular Expressions:

[javascript regex to extract anchor text and URL from anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369147/javascript-regex-to-extract-anchor-text-and-url-from-anchor-tags)

```
var url_match = /https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/;

alert(url_match.test("http://stackoverflow.com"));
```

Comment: Exactly, this only returns IF it matches the Regex, not the parts.