# How to extract a URL from a Tweet with a JavaScript RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

Assuming that I have the tweet stored as a string in a JS variable...

How to extract a URL from a tweet with a JavaScript RegEx?

This should be much easier than extracting a URL from a string, because:

I will assume that anything that starts with http or www and ends with a blank space (or end of tweet) is a URL.

Comment: You just need a JS regex that matches URLs. There are plenty of questions on SO which answer that.

Comment: I looked around, but I don't see any good answers. For example, these don't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043098/extract-url-from-string-with-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one of the regular expressions that I've used for pulling links from Twitter statuses.

**Link Match Pattern**

```
(?:<\w+.*?>|[^=!:'"/]|^)((?:https?://|www\.)[-\w]+(?:\.[-\w]+)*(?::\d+)?(?:/(?:(?:[~\w\+%-]|(?:[,.;@:][^\s$]))+)?)*(?:\?[\w\+%&=.;:-]+)?(?:\#[\w\-\.]*)?)(?:\p{P}|\s|<|$)
```

Alternatively, if you control how the statuses are fetched from Twitter, you can pass the `include_entities` parameter to [statuses/show](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/%3aid) (or any other method that supports it, such as [statuses/user_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline)) to have Twitter break out the links, mentions, and hashtags for you, like the following:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/23918022347456512.json?include_entities=true

In the resultant JSON, notice the **entities** object.

```
"entities":{"urls":[{"expanded_url":null,"indices":[27,53],"url":"http:\/\/tinyurl.com\/38wp7nt"}],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[]}
```

Now, you can reference the data returned from Twitter rather than having to parse it yourself.  The best things about this approach are you offload the work to Twitter, and never have to worry whether your regular expression will match with Twitter's exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringToCheck = "http://www.something";

stringToCheck.match(/^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$/); // returns true if stringToCheck is a URL
```

This will check for two or 3 letter TLDs and accounts for subdomains.

Comment: The string I'm try to check is a Twitter tweet. So, stringToCheck would be something like: "Check out the awesome http://www.something.com" or "The www.something.com is awesome!"

Comment: stringToCheck.match(/\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))/); // returns true if stringToCheck is a URL