# How to identify url in tweet using R

Tags: r, url, twitter, tweets

I want to identify those tweets containing URL in my twitter data set. For example, using the sign of "http://".

How to proceed it in R? for example the tweets texts are

```
  "@RainxDog @twitpic Please HELP #OccupyWallStreet and RT this video: http://t.co/vjwNR7TC"

  "@degamuna Please HELP #OccupyWallStreet and RT this video: http://t.co/vjwNR7TC"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grep

```
if(length(grep("http://",data))>0){
 data[grep("http://",data)]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your relatively simple question, hides something that is actually very tricky. In your two examples, the urls:

1. were of the form: `http://t.cp/` - what about `bit.ly` links? What about `https`?
2. the urls appeared at the end of the tweet. What about urls in the middle or start of the tweet?

Construct a set of sample tweets and make sure that your regular expression works.

Basically, you need a regular expression. Stackoverflow questions to look at are:

1. [How to extract a URL from a Tweet with a JavaScript RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240973/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-tweet-with-a-javascript-regex)
2. [What's the cleanest way to extract URLs from a string using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python)

These questions also contain links.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the URLs of a tweet using [Twitter Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities). When you make the REST call, make sure you include

```
&include_entities=true
```

This will give you a section in the JSON or XML called entities. There will be a child node called urls.

Here's an example of what will be returned.

```
"text": "Twitter for Mac is now easier and faster, and you can open multiple windows at once http://t.co/0JG5Mcq",

    "entities": {

      "media": [

      ],

      "urls": [

        {

          "url": "http://t.co/0JG5Mcq",

          "display_url": "blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitte…",

          "expanded_url": "http://blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitter-for-mac-update.html",

          "indices": [

            84,

            103

          ]

        }

      ],

      "user_mentions": [

      ],

      "hashtags": [

      ]

    }
```

So, look for entities -> urls to see if a tweet contains a link to an external site.