# How to remove HTML tags from textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, textarea

I'm loading text from database but I'd like to remove html link code from it with JavaScript.

So lets say the textarea right now displays:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://stackoverflow.com//questions/ask">http://stackoverflow.com//questions/ask</a> - good page
```

and I want it to display:

```
http://stackoverflow.com//questions/ask - good page
```

Is there something lightweight I could use that would work for multiple links in the same textarea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript/822486#822486), use the browser's HTML parsing abilities to get this done right.

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}
jQuery('#textareaid').text(function(index, text){
 return strip(text);
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Au95R/1/

(Edited to use cleaner JS)

Comment: Bear in mind that in IE8 innerText will not respect newlines `\r\n`, and as a result it can seriously mess with the content of a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strip_tag()` like in PHP: http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535

```
textareacontent = strip_tags(textareacontent, "<b><i>"); // remove all HTML except <b> and <i>.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using regular expressions. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369147/javascript-regex-to-extract-anchor-text-and-url-from-anchor-tags) is a question on stack overflow itself and the answer explains it well