# HTML scraping in PDI spoon step (user defined java class)

Tags: java, regex, pentaho, data-integration

Hi am using the `HTTP Client` step to get the source code of a website. I need to scrape out a particular part of one line.

example line: `<a href="....." ......>TEXT I WANT</a>`

so I figured I would use a UDJC in PDI and first split the text block into lines with `String[] lines = code.split("\n+");` and then loop through the array and with an if condition (i.e. the regex check) see if I have the right line.

```
for(String line : lines){
        if line.matches(".*a href.*"){
            String outputString = code;
            break;
        }
    }
```

(I am trying this also in an IDE as pure java without PDI) I never get a hit though. Any idea how to fix this? Or is there a faster and easier way to get the chunk I want?

Comment: if your particular `<a>` tag is identifiable in some way, I'd suggest parsing as XML and using XPath to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like you want to in a similar case with a filter-step

Transformation-Steps:

1. generate row with field "dom", type string IMPORTANT: Limit should be 1
   // pentaho needs a field for https-step, which is not needed in the
   following steps
2. http-step, get the html-dump and set a fieldname "html" or something like that for it (maybe a status-code field would be good)
   // Check with a preview if the data is there
3. filter-step: http includes `"<a href"`
   // check the output
4. JavaScript-Step with your regex*, define a new field with yout wanted output

* [for the regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369147/javascript-regex-to-extract-anchor-text-and-url-from-anchor-tags)