# How to get source link for blogs in liferay?

Tags: liferay-6

I have been using Liferay 6.2 ***BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil*** API in order to access blog entries. These blogs are generated automatically once i enable Rss Feeds from liferay.

Using ***BlogsEntryModel*** [as shown here](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/blogs/model/BlogsEntryModel.html) i can access various properties like title, description, date etc. But i could not access the source link for each of the blog content as it is not availble in the blogsEntryModel. Is there any other way to access source link of blog contents generated from Rss feeds?

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: As a workaround i used Regular Expression to match anchor tag. Found from post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369147/javascript-regex-to-extract-anchor-text-and-url-from-anchor-tags

Comment: what's a "source link"? Also, I don't understand how they "are generated automatically once i enable Rss Feeds"... please clarify

Comment: Hi @olaf, Once i enable Rss feeds, i can see various blog entries being created. If i open this blog entry, i see at the end of content there is a link that points to the original article. Since i am accessing these blog entries and their properties, programatically, i was wondering if  i could get the source of each blog entry as well.